# How to not post a form if validation is false?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, validation

Basically, I have a form in a PHP document that is posting to itself to save into my database. Although, I would like to only `post` this form if it validates correctly.

I need to validate this with Javascript and determine whether or not it should be posted.

If my validation function returns `false`, then the form should not be submitted. If my validation function returns `true`, then the form should be submitted.

I do not want to validate this server side with PHP since all my code is client side within the Javascript and would be an absolute nightmare to transfer it all to the server side.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: There's a JQuery validation plug-in that's fairly straight-forward to use...

Comment: `I do not want to validate this server side` then why validate at all. The server side validation is the important one.

Comment: @Musa - I cannot validate server side due to how my code is formatted. I was passed on this project for another developer and it would be a nightmare to transfer it to server side since this is a fixed rate project.

Comment: @paulsm4 - But it will still be `posted` to my PHP since it is posting directly to itself `method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>"`

Comment: @paulsm4 - That is exactly what I am doing. Validating a ton of it client side, and validating it slightly on the server side before it is processed into my database.

Comment: nightmare to do versus very easy to bypass security? depends on if you want any thing inserting into your database. ie, What happens when I use your form with javascript turned off?

Comment: @James - This is a very small project and something like that would never happen. This is for an admin area of a website and only 1 user will ever use it.

Comment: horses for courses. fair enough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Michelle is correct: most Javascript frameworks (including jQuery and Dojo) offer a rich set of powerful tools that simplify client-side validation.

2) In principle, it's actually quite easy: just add an "onsubmit()" handler to your form:

- [JavaScript Form Validation](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp)

  Email:

Somewhere (for example, in your HTML header), you have a Javascript function "validateForm()".  If the function returns "false", the form will *NOT* be posted to the remote server.

I believe this is exactly what you want, correct?

Comment: So you're saying that I could simply just add an `onsubmit()` handler to my form, and within that `onsubmit` I could validate everything. If everything validates as `true`, I could then `post` the form using Javascript?

Comment: You *could* post the form with Javascript, if you wanted to do a bit more work.  But by default, the form post automatically if you have a "submit" button and if your custom "onsubmit()" returns "true".

Comment: Just gave it a test, and it works perfectly. It was exactly what I needed, yes :) Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Although, I try to place an `alert` within my validation function and it will not show. Is this just because the function is meant for returning a boolean value and nothing else?

Answer (score 1):

In the HTML form, you need to latch onto the ["onsubmit" event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_form_onsubmit.asp). This tag attribute executes a hunk of javascript when the submit button is pressed. The form is only POSTed, however, when the javascript returns a TRUE value. In order to stop the POST request, simply return FALSE Examples can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp).

Comment: Ahhhh. So if I add `onsubmit="return validateForm();"` to my form, it will only `post` to my PHP if it returns true?